# Is it possible to have a final, unnamed argument with Apache CLI?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons-cli

I want to be able to have arguments in the following form:

```
./mything -arg1 hey -arg2 ho filename
```

So an optional arg1, an optional arg2, and then an unnamed last argument. I was wondering if there is a way to do this with Apache CLI? I can just grab it from the argument to main, but that seems janky.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7):

Apache CLI has a method `getArgList()` which returns all not handled options and arguments from the command line. This will do the job.